# user defined datetime input in java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, date-difference

i wanted to take an input of date and time in the below format and need to calculate the time difference between two, can anyone suggest how to take below string as input and calculate the time difference.

user defined datetime input in java

```
String startTime= "11/27/2018+09:00:00";
String endTime= "11/28/2018+13:00:00";
```

The `+` is a separator (not a sign as in plus or minus).

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter` and `Duration` from the `java.time` API

Comment: search for 1) java input string from console 2) java parse string to date 3) java difference between LocalDate(s)

Comment: @Roopesh Have you tried anything from yourself?

Comment: What is the expected result in this case? Sorry, it’s not immediately clear since I don’t see any time of day in your input. 20 hours? 24 hours? 1 day? Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ole it’s in 24hours format.

Comment: I didn’t get that. Sorry, but are you sure you did? Asking because I think that `+09:00` looks like a UTC offset, not a time of day. Your format seems to resemble [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE), only with `11/27/2018` instead of `2018-11-27`.

Comment: @Ole thanks for correcting me actually the format is “MM/DD/YYYY+09:00:00” + is string separater.

Comment: Please fix the broken Shift key on your keyboard. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, a resource for posterity, not a casual chat room.

Answer (score 1):

## Senseless input

```
String startTime= "11/27/2018+09:00";
String endTime= "11/28/2018+13:00";
```

These inputs do not make sense. Applying an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) such as `+09:00` to a date such as `11/27/2018` has no meaning.

For an offset to have meaning, **you need a date *and* a time-of-day**.

We can make a guess and *assume* the people sending the data meant the first moment of the day. If so, they should have said so by including that in the data.

The trick here is that some dates in some time zones do *not* always start at 00:00:00 time-of-day. Anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) mean the day may start at a time such as 01:00:00. Unfortunately, your input has only an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (a number of hours-minutes-seconds) rather than a time zone (`Continent/Region` name). A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. Without a time zone, we cannot look up the rules to know the anomalies.

The best you could do is assume the day starts at 00:00:00 and ignore the reality of any anomalies. But this is guesswork and inadvisable. The real solution is to educate the publisher of your data about two things when exchanging date-time values: (a) Use UTC rather than an offset or zone, and (b) write strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

### Guesswork

If correcting the source of this data is not feasible, then we can plod on with guesswork.

Extract the date, separate from offset.

```
String input = "11/27/2018+09:00";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input.substring( 0 , 10 ) , f );
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of( input.substring( 11 ) );
```

> localDate.toString(): 2018-11-27
>
> zoneOffset.toString(): +09:00

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( localDate , LocalTime.MIN , zoneOffset );
```

> 2018-11-27T00:00+09:00

We can calculate elapsed time as a `Duration`. But beware, without the context of time zones, we cannot account for any anomalies that may be occurring in this time period, as discussed above. With only offsets rather than zones, calculations are made using generic 24-hour days. So, again, **this is just sloppy guesswork**, not a reliable solution.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( odt , odtLater ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 there is:
`LocalDateTime`: use this if you need to deal with date and time.
`LocalDate`: use this if you need to deal with date only.
`ZonedDateTime`: use this if you need to deal with date time with time zone.
`OffsetDateTime`: use this if you need to deal with date time with offset. (the most suitable for your case)

Your case is only use Date and Offset, it's a bit tricky since time zone and offset can only be applied to LocalDateTime (not only date).

However, I think you can solved it like this:

Create a method that convert your date string into `OffsetDateTime` like this:

```
private static OffsetDateTime createZonedDateTime (String dateWithTimeOffset)
{
    //TODO: assert that dateWithTimeOffset is valid
    String date = dateWithTimeOffset.substring (0, 10);
    String timeOffset = dateWithTimeOffset.substring (10, 13);

    //define your date pattern
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ("MM/dd/yyyy");

    return LocalDate.parse (date, formatter) // create LocalDate
                .atStartOfDay () // convert it to LocalDateTime with time 00:00:00
                .atOffset (ZoneOffset.of(timeOffset)); // apply the offset
}
```

Then you can simple create your `OffsetDateTime` like this:

```
OffsetDateTime startTime = stringToZonedDateTime ("11/27/2018+09:00");  
OffsetDateTime endTime = stringToZonedDateTime ("11/28/2018+13:00");
```

You can create duration using `OffsetDateTime` like this:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between (startTime, endTime);
```

Duration have everything you need related with time duration, for example:

```
duration.toHours () // will give you the hour duration
```

Comment: @karthik I tried the other way by taking the System time and calculating the difference, and am not expecting the program to be done by other, I just want to know the methods how to implement.

Comment: @BasilBourque, Thanks for your input. I have updated my answer.
And thanks for point out `OffsetDateTime` I am not aware of this before.